# Qt: Change the icon in a QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview, qicon

Is there a way to change the icon of an element in a `QListView` after it has been displayed?

I can't find a way to do a `setData` with the `DecorationRole` (the role used for the icon).

The model used is a custom `QFileSystemModel`, but the default implementation is only good for the `EditRole` so to change the name of the item.

I'm don't know how the the overridden `setData` can be done.

The goal is to change the icon when the mouse is over the item (through `mouseMoveEvent`)

Comment: Subclass `QFileSystemModel` and pad `DecorationRole` to `setData`? But then you need to know where to set the icon to so that the view can access it via model's`data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subclass `QListView` and implement the behavior that changes the role of the displayed icon when the mouse hovers over the item.

Such a subclass could use an internal proxy model so that it wouldn't need to mess with the base view's painting. Simply inform the proxy that a given item's decoration role data has changed, and the base view will know what to do.

Comment: I don't understand what "changing the role of the displayed icon" means or implies.

Comment: @user3842408 The source model provides two icons, default under the DecorationRole, and a hover one under a custom role. The proxy redirects requests for the DecorationRole data to either the same role, or the custom hover role, depending on directions from the subclassed view.